# Customize File Picker position on screen

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to customize window's file picker panel's position when it's appear. Is it possible in UWP C#? Does it exist any API for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to customize window's file picker panel's position when it's appear.

Unfortunately, currently there is no [such api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker?view=winrt-22000) could custom file picker's position. and the picker window is system level, it's window position was manage by system. If you do want to custom file picker position, you may post your feature request with windows feed back hub app.